# Updating nested collection inside document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following document inside Mongo:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e9852b2b803bfc66e74a6"), 
    "name" : "NAME", 
    "collection1" : [ 
        { "type" : "TYPE", "collection2" : [ ] } 
    ] 
}
```

I would like to add elements in the ***collection2*** attribute. I am using the mongo console.

I tried using this query:

```
db.mycollection.updateOne(
{"name": "NAME"}, 
{$addToSet: {"collection1.$[element].collection2" : { $each: ["a", "b", "c"]}}}, 
{arrayFilters: [{element: 0}]}
);
```

I also tried to use push, but with no success.

The console returns:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update didn't update the document because the `arrayFilters` clause did not match the document. Specifically, your example is filtering on an element in `collection1` that is defined as `0`, which does not exist.

Changing the update to filter on `collection2` being an empty array should result in the update working as expected:

```
db.test.insert({
...     "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e9852b2b803bfc66e74a6"),
...     "name" : "NAME",
...     "collection1" : [
...         { "type" : "TYPE", "collection2" : [ ] }
...     ]
... })

db.test.update(
... { name: "NAME" },
... { "$addToSet": { collection1.$[element].collection2: { "$each" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] } } },
... { arrayFilters: [ { element.collection2: [ ] } ] }
... )

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e9852b2b803bfc66e74a6"), "name" : "NAME", "collection1" : [ { "type" : "TYPE", "collection2" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] } ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of `collection1` element you can omit `arrayFilters` and just use the index

```
db.mycollection.updateOne(
    { "name": "NAME" }, 
    { $addToSet: { "collection1.0.collection2": { $each: ["a", "b", "c"] }}}
);
```